Color scale is re-evaluated on rendering
When the graphics are rendered again, the ColorData is taken from new definitions while the PlotRange and BarLegend range are not. Which part of this forces the redefinition? (And how can I stop it?)
pr = {0, 1};
aplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 3}], PlotRange -> pr, 
  ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", ImageSize -> 200, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, pr]] &, pr}]]]
pr = {0, 2};
Show[aplot]



Not an answer, but an observation: Using RuleDelayed for Epilog gives a different behavior. aplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 3}], PlotRange -> pr,    ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", ImageSize -> 200,    Epilog :>     Inset[BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, pr]] &, pr}]]].  My guess is that Inset is causing the rescaling.

@CraigCarter You're right, using RuleDelayed renders both the BarLegend colorbar and the BarLegend axes to 2.

Also, note that the Epilog depends on pr (FullForm[Epilog /. AbsoluteOptions[aplot]])  which puzzles me.  Further, Clear[pr]; Show[aplot]  doesn't break aplot  this puzzles me too.  Neither BarLegend or Inset have a "Hold*" attribute.

Function is HoldAll, take a look at InputForm@aplot[[2]], does it address your doubts?

@Kuba OK, I can see that pr is evaluated in one place and unevaluated in another place, I still don't understand why or what to do about it.

Both versions provide the same result.
Using /. q -> pr.
pr = {0, 1};
aplot = ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 3}], PlotRange -> pr, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", ImageSize -> 180, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, q]] &, pr}]]] /. 
  q -> pr
pr = {0, 2};
aplot

Or using With.
pr = {0, 1};
aplot = With[{q = pr}, 
  ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 3}], PlotRange -> pr, 
   ColorFunction -> "RedBlueTones", ImageSize -> 180, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, q]] &, pr}]]]]
pr = {0, 2};
aplot




Great, but which part of the expression has the property HoldAll?

@ninemileskid I think the function ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, pr]] &.
